# Array of JSON in @RequestParam in Spring MVC

Tags: json, spring

I am sending the following JSON to a controller and trying to access it but i am getting "The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect." error message.

JSON :

```
{
"employees": [
{
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Doe"
},
{
    "firstName": "Anna",
    "lastName": "Smith"
},
{
    "firstName": "Peter",
    "lastName": "Jones"
}
]}
```

controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/xyz",produces="application/json",consumes="application/json",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String sendEmpDetails(@RequestBody List<Employee> employeeList){
    return "xyz";
}
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: this link might help you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14208682/the-request-sent-by-the-client-was-syntactically-incorrect-spring-restclie

Answer (score 0):

You are using a complex object, but only need an array of List, so build your JSON like this:

```
    var items = [];
    {
        var item = {};
        item ["firstName"] = "John";
        item ["lastName"] = "Doe";
        items.push(item);
    }
    {
        var item = {};
        item ["firstName"] = "Anna";
        item ["lastName"] = "Smith";
        items.push(item);
    }
    {
        var item = {};
        item ["firstName"] = "Peter";
        item ["lastName"] = "Jones";
        items.push(item);
    }
    $.ajax({
        url: '/myurl',
        data: JSON.stringify(items),
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (response) {
            alert(response);
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, errorThrown) {
            alert(errorThrown);
        }
    }
```